# PHP Scrape Embed - Says no Flash is Installed

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to scrape data from a webpage with a video on it. The video I'm trying to scrape looks like...

```
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
    src="/player.swf" width="560" height="440" 
    style="undefined" id="mediaplayer" name="mediaplayer" 
    quality="high" allowfullscreen="true" wmode="opaque" 
    allowscriptaccess="always" bgcolor="#000000" 
    flashvars="width=560&amp;height=440&amp;autostart=true&amp;fullscreen=true&amp;file=FILEHERE">
```

What I'm getting when I scrape the div that contains the embed is...

```
<div id="player" >
    <font size="2"><u><b><a target="_self" class="b" href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/">
        ATTENTION:<br />This video will not play. You currently do not have Adobe Flash installed on this computer. Please click here to download it (it's free!)
    </a></b></u></font>
</div>
```

Based on what is received, my domain doesn't have flash installed. How should I scrape the webpage to grab the embed element correctly?

Comment: Likely the flash player is injected via Javascript after the fact, while the original HTML only contains this warning text...!?

Comment: Any idea on how I should mimic a flash injection like you're speaking of?